# Query the Facebook Graph API for objects containing a given string

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, ios9

I'm looking to get back photos from a specific album on Facebook that contain a given string in their title.  Can this be done?  The only alternative I know of would be to download ALL photos from the album (at the moment there's about 500 and this number will grow over time), parse them all and then eventually filter.  That could become (and already kind of is) an extremely costly operation I'm looking to avoid.

I have looked all over and have yet to find anything somewhat related, so if there's an answer to this question already please link me to it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do have to go through the album, there is no Search API for that.

1. `/album-id/photos`
2. check for the string in the title
3. use paging to get the next batch of photos
4. repeat from number 2 until there is no next batch

You can also cache the ids/titles for later, so you don´t have to hit the API for a all the photos in a new search, but that´s completely up to you. There is no other way.

Comment: That's what i'm doing-  it's not that I can stop once I find what I'm looking for, there can be multiple results, so I need to check every photo.  Only problem is it's taking almost 10 seconds to page and parse all 500+ photos :(

Comment: i understand, but there is no other way. you can only cache the photos and/or their title, so you don´t have to go through all of them for every search.